# Add a column with repeating values taken from another data.frame

Tags: r

everybody! I have the following data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(CNTRYID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Czech Republic", 
"Denmark", "France", "Greece", "Hungary", "Italy", "Lithuania", 
"Netherlands", "Poland", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
"United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"), class = "factor"), 
    PVLIT1 = c(341.73556, 327.75647, 333.99133, 299.23201, 274.26806, 
    330.20199, 290.3974, 245.60594, 305.04734, 322.12211, 264.19379, 
    283.34121, 286.62649, 301.27084, 204.67276, 339.7475, 350.74884, 
    300.41595, 338.76949, 340.92763, 323.86579, 320.03587, 276.43592, 
    307.12426, 290.60296, 322.23858, 299.0517, 328.35244, 267.82705, 
    245.1432, 322.43248, 352.37208, 275.75408, 317.75532, 332.75897, 
    321.23265, 315.338, 303.61999, 309.63271, 315.13702, 349.31912, 
    330.28415, 291.53027, 238.86247, 336.98836, 312.80759, 312.32254, 
    238.765, 268.14566, 326.59843, 298.99782, 372.8563, 314.59135, 
    267.68085, 358.00259, 293.74775, 257.99369, 352.46286, 277.74005, 
    340.21297, 343.90215, 365.2711, 298.95923, 347.24665, 288.41685, 
    267.28314, 299.62821, 288.50113, 346.33, 348.62584, 304.37408, 
    288.28595, 209.42411, 308.3979, 317.11152, 339.05234, 338.79844, 
    273.4862, 317.05362, 321.9683, 298.49502, 315.31917, 285.24075, 
    260.5942, 292.17127, 278.49578, 351.55043, 291.29336, 345.61643, 
    252.87387, 318.81766, 359.97134, 334.8103, 282.96817, 347.12409, 
    266.44512, 284.23384, 303.45264, 228.6119, 248.62507, 445.14543, 
    262.78094, 330.89695, 276.94543, 340.09174, 370.30567, 254.49489, 
    267.31821, 235.36262, 268.87887, 293.34609, 323.89632, 332.1124, 
    270.03193, 302.92495, 290.86264, 330.11303, 225.08377, 306.51173, 
    393.41635, 296.14069, 290.8399, 249.71853, 273.45073, 391.61765, 
    229.62298, 368.49384, 352.84141, 276.27584, 271.89748, 345.33152, 
    279.98931, 322.87181, 262.99515, 251.44921, 291.01078, 302.7094, 
    288.9321, 335.60061, 353.84158, 225.1918, 267.17191, 261.80763, 
    291.8125, 354.75112, 263.19101, 300.22572, 309.91597, 323.37047, 
    371.69579, 288.89204, 344.10129, 211.20385, 268.50285, 347.76109, 
    223.8669, 280.59382, 341.03251, 330.07897, 297.91223, 382.22934, 
    346.63016, 279.97218, 296.75031, 279.52446, 239.17915, 307.47267, 
    310.66321, 339.9095, 288.07157, 313.38334, 294.49606, 301.16477, 
    330.97285, 306.29201, 258.9723, 305.16945, 220.56537, 293.92923, 
    316.1579, 294.9318, 231.12861, 327.08462, 295.45707, 212.56843, 
    343.58854, 321.65331, 347.51206, 327.05139, 270.26912, 245.49499, 
    284.13733, 346.38385, 262.40319, 305.82358, 268.60343, 314.58164, 
    247.77339, 346.95623, 326.82632, 296.7529, 252.09381, 307.30177, 
    262.73407, 261.99723, 265.99006, 297.02533, 221.36089, 342.78459, 
    259.3387, 308.40893, 345.39162, 252.01223, 249.46163, 232.65253, 
    295.11341, 269.32542, 270.33917, 311.52152, 295.45142, 299.57599, 
    264.36488, 253.78787, 277.27982, 184.86342, 343.89483, 304.73262, 
    315.47804, 277.46603, 294.02264, 278.49927, 288.03195, 261.12088, 
    258.48768, 286.84427, 232.02021, 239.09253, 249.53217, 341.65779, 
    199.08805, 348.26952, 292.84918, 233.47102, 280.34833, 266.45888, 
    300.40607, 287.81728, 293.79174, 257.01624, 375.42354, 212.49236, 
    326.45861, 266.21237, 282.09158, 273.21422, 226.8083, 320.00889, 
    300.76454, 261.39701, 263.16525, 325.74916, 285.175, 297.7344, 
    266.98718, 287.35748, 295.33917, 310.84685, 235.88418, 335.12738, 
    338.0637, 263.95686, 341.24316, 344.17478, 277.19368, 292.86124, 
    306.71616, 302.24125, 292.9568, 327.03543, 273.10249, 246.17394, 
    329.32818, 289.45179, 329.58524, 316.57873, 254.53541, 307.42027, 
    340.46333, 260.72247, 177.1923, 298.05925, 229.80109, 299.93516, 
    298.97657, 296.32594, 331.81735, 335.73543, 348.6484, 224.40826, 
    339.58894, 230.45043, 297.69392, 250.64399, 216.37015, 248.48309, 
    315.3377, 259.91751, 343.96253, 238.19071, 268.7662, 195.30995, 
    295.58828, 282.90717, 257.23455, 312.86206, 255.33727, 293.08026, 
    321.61584, 352.64202, 331.90932, 291.72882, 301.87908, 299.83755, 
    276.29271, 288.31371, 173.19914, 235.98186, 267.68055, 273.57641, 
    259.38568, 282.82247, 255.2055, 259.92553, 324.37237, 323.27084, 
    297.1294, 293.29913, 319.26816, 296.19763, 287.20711, 120.7633, 
    299.14635, 324.02645, 272.24852, 280.46404, 363.56726, 213.18303, 
    318.84395, 307.23832, 337.49138, 352.61447, 295.99838, 245.2863, 
    303.07131, 200.14136, 314.2698, 290.86413, 289.6412, 232.13515, 
    328.96702, 250.57396, 251.36983, 259.23267, 277.98361, 306.61626, 
    298.90864, 336.54659, 270.34128, 295.23666, 289.28454, 314.25576, 
    305.90498, 223.59499, 297.3472, 302.97199, 306.82586, 293.8622, 
    277.52691, 274.99887, 309.28188, 243.9094, 287.04775, 332.49858, 
    316.85995, 227.84818, 338.34644, 231.03199, 280.42949, 326.23743, 
    287.90662, 308.44719, 224.65553, 255.51269, 320.01916, 284.76909, 
    310.07218, 305.64163, 267.90448, 291.91266, 311.95645, 234.77883, 
    288.47911, 337.66548, 235.67435, 328.26341, 217.05384, 271.18711, 
    256.92855, 306.35037, 298.57583, 220.25599, 305.70531, 397.23308, 
    243.34537, 318.81272, 287.84564, 291.19244, 260.50231, 309.29317, 
    288.32053, 285.65509, 270.71887, 349.55511, 266.04791, 305.22095, 
    259.29735, 283.99375, 281.30021, 368.59316, 300.66732, 253.21196, 
    277.61171, 313.79851, 310.08222, 288.8469, 329.40954, 324.01478, 
    283.84872, 293.73975, 175.58543, 287.87392, 304.40044, 294.23277, 
    268.17933, 309.02819, 253.19897, 265.68756, 290.41261, 333.8446, 
    248.33467, 298.56631, 196.18183, 249.01214, 239.07566, 272.0436, 
    266.38371, 244.71529, 230.62195, 280.98915, 327.92842, 291.64174, 
    290.58153, 278.05094, 242.61752, 290.2778, 349.53173, 206.13951, 
    293.64674, 201.95774, 353.00234, 301.41944, 266.58184, 313.45438, 
    290.98948, 287.79774, 334.35567, 276.27736, 271.85967, 233.80236, 
    275.925, 292.44499, 275.67027, 306.44843, 293.76468, 300.68248, 
    277.37136, 258.36308, 215.93238, 304.53151, 282.98405, 284.24563, 
    267.54523, 278.81698, 293.47491, 274.20848, 325.56625, 338.29286, 
    237.04901, 321.03634, 284.59905), PVLIT2 = c(329.96437, 309.7071, 
    323.76923, 311.6131, 296.0494, 320.40846, 316.35148, 284.25026, 
    305.10127, 317.73826, 279.00676, 311.32111, 263.20577, 295.35872, 
    247.77471, 312.83461, 338.78073, 306.69291, 323.277, 324.9266, 
    286.49722, 317.47413, 294.87445, 332.89844, 285.07891, 294.75732, 
    312.38012, 307.31727, 281.80926, 299.38988, 307.64408, 359.26622, 
    269.06506, 311.84518, 335.81958, 320.7753, 261.46395, 254.00522, 
    322.33784, 304.60692, 330.96759, 348.84054, 308.38673, 246.73035, 
    330.95077, 351.57083, 307.36752, 255.48044, 269.63236, 347.14345, 
    315.88441, 400.94726, 296.03271, 276.19477, 363.93767, 309.51741, 
    249.73923, 359.06376, 268.23778, 340.45045, 347.93015, 331.94389, 
    265.17793, 339.92872, 302.63463, 271.15349, 287.00579, 245.92875, 
    333.74443, 395.13695, 319.19868, 280.50088, 274.27643, 298.57925, 
    301.34704, 343.32807, 322.24002, 260.04914, 305.97704, 299.22391, 
    311.31108, 314.82843, 284.82475, 263.54816, 305.83341, 275.05002, 
    291.21003, 295.85667, 325.4418, 297.35548, 328.91424, 348.46255, 
    374.91294, 278.72346, 336.15884, 284.42308, 301.46666, 280.60555, 
    221.60585, 240.95952, 352.39105, 244.17594, 331.78841, 288.21081, 
    311.62633, 360.55586, 252.44882, 275.11625, 224.22946, 263.59549, 
    275.29046, 321.90792, 332.09749, 282.92641, 282.89338, 292.94236, 
    329.33191, 242.67135, 284.59736, 372.01791, 284.58945, 304.33581, 
    262.18477, 263.41397, 397.0077, 233.13107, 354.51546, 330.58595, 
    267.95011, 272.97652, 320.41706, 269.92821, 311.25004, 248.15808, 
    260.19179, 278.38501, 314.36786, 296.30594, 295.8064, 362.28497, 
    236.54304, 280.39167, 268.16006, 282.61124, 328.43024, 266.80519, 
    272.71165, 317.02057, 302.61842, 313.83703, 299.44275, 347.81048, 
    248.96742, 244.98621, 314.78989, 228.19594, 277.08832, 321.66255, 
    307.59243, 285.20515, 329.42832, 327.38645, 266.39655, 284.52323, 
    253.67779, 239.9784, 315.34247, 324.64586, 339.56843, 334.15503, 
    324.9195, 289.38614, 279.53691, 346.34106, 299.6327, 264.50415, 
    329.80362, 257.43317, 310.62546, 325.04705, 266.05947, 252.10474, 
    377.03047, 284.46253, 252.06975, 307.29189, 325.21219, 318.36119, 
    313.92387, 266.27629, 236.96554, 308.785, 327.27422, 260.62932, 
    298.31588, 266.69611, 343.64082, 249.20663, 368.61185, 314.38577, 
    296.44633, 301.93329, 305.82456, 234.26794, 285.09993, 264.74247, 
    291.16644, 261.86653, 326.92465, 271.35729, 298.4598, 315.83039, 
    251.59546, 248.09457, 250.90401, 313.28557, 281.10513, 289.41966, 
    322.99908, 308.48391, 303.46002, 259.34959, 285.41517, 276.54708, 
    215.90873, 320.46273, 307.92637, 329.45411, 280.43586, 319.99516, 
    295.35201, 270.81816, 260.6502, 277.0142, 285.64532, 217.5607, 
    245.98812, 226.29258, 309.23674, 220.03202, 387.01331, 268.84682, 
    248.05849, 279.63382, 285.34802, 284.09757, 273.3005, 259.08111, 
    264.10347, 386.52038, 210.39955, 320.20292, 245.43105, 301.72215, 
    262.78873, 207.51776, 329.13312, 321.57565, 258.19365, 291.23977, 
    310.97158, 272.66014, 259.28731, 246.29506, 319.95987, 294.63771, 
    311.32836, 312.20071, 350.12412, 308.50961, 237.55051, 343.6281, 
    340.66271, 297.44784, 331.91189, 276.27969, 301.48287, 321.79642, 
    285.85259, 256.98003, 267.14263, 334.84721, 348.23387, 322.91747, 
    268.42791, 269.33266, 334.05385, 319.43236, 270.38822, 168.24661, 
    327.46855, 248.39576, 294.05205, 318.50606, 312.98079, 287.35827, 
    361.43941, 342.54578, 247.997, 316.69669, 232.59609, 285.6277, 
    261.74517, 230.28962, 254.88764, 302.1326, 267.05801, 385.75184, 
    267.35567, 313.20042, 203.28131, 282.90967, 290.01701, 282.52713, 
    339.58608, 266.53576, 297.53657, 278.7528, 348.01977, 328.51913, 
    289.18677, 319.62583, 311.31862, 271.67348, 279.98333, 227.36405, 
    276.27979, 290.28081, 280.66062, 255.47229, 291.26037, 264.89911, 
    304.19635, 330.39094, 334.60314, 272.9507, 294.44286, 346.35474, 
    332.11805, 313.19078, 104.71963, 293.40003, 329.98007, 247.70109, 
    259.13664, 325.72004, 239.1354, 294.74629, 291.78074, 328.38065, 
    334.70175, 312.16118, 215.75044, 297.27003, 202.36576, 271.84798, 
    291.59486, 303.22928, 221.18819, 315.37282, 238.00923, 233.12403, 
    269.9957, 259.90847, 311.6859, 272.51505, 346.11677, 260.70023, 
    275.42651, 290.61255, 307.04942, 323.60677, 219.96542, 305.55666, 
    283.99912, 267.52644, 285.16624, 301.02858, 260.05581, 283.41617, 
    244.09153, 290.04512, 353.63745, 317.37715, 241.34487, 321.14259, 
    258.36885, 261.37509, 348.62232, 300.73864, 327.22453, 228.55662, 
    268.91226, 314.09536, 260.56452, 283.06898, 319.64052, 275.96927, 
    296.46456, 295.56963, 276.68877, 289.44363, 296.45405, 240.71778, 
    310.15017, 237.00255, 240.61887, 244.14616, 316.83501, 253.25562, 
    230.76127, 304.57009, 364.11619, 267.0067, 308.55546, 275.38505, 
    293.96026, 243.73364, 321.01363, 316.79925, 277.67496, 289.51552, 
    307.85001, 279.01546, 317.36872, 242.91248, 279.70631, 226.23475, 
    386.36518, 326.81052, 235.98733, 288.59577, 305.13604, 353.10836, 
    274.67248, 327.51103, 322.45477, 315.17773, 316.73504, 189.05388, 
    267.47862, 316.6865, 272.59329, 281.07099, 327.16369, 280.24953, 
    253.59041, 314.05915, 341.81589, 286.40082, 323.2246, 218.71734, 
    256.56632, 239.05101, 292.73646, 262.55946, 280.23444, 219.2759, 
    293.2041, 342.50186, 251.37571, 321.82169, 290.32648, 233.07586, 
    293.06438, 333.05446, 222.39499, 298.17628, 201.93622, 354.07415, 
    294.31312, 301.73295, 328.2708, 278.76013, 289.11145, 313.0081, 
    275.55262, 287.71408, 272.14237, 300.88391, 308.66827, 284.93954, 
    312.92511, 335.31426, 276.17927, 320.79382, 273.71349, 255.89581, 
    300.24576, 292.25961, 288.96434, 303.44888, 253.07684, 248.08721, 
    281.36322, 326.35893, 335.85343, 253.90892, 328.49694, 272.70062
    ), PVLIT3 = c(347.03202, 297.99638, 308.9164, 300.68665, 
    302.42232, 318.3244, 315.16283, 273.26457, 306.98393, 342.15998, 
    271.74761, 330.01561, 239.3113, 292.38404, 220.32939, 320.98693, 
    328.77846, 312.25874, 320.16997, 315.01401, 278.54675, 297.93796, 
    289.05429, 306.41476, 292.88945, 287.35494, 289.7173, 327.61128, 
    256.59233, 270.40046, 299.88817, 347.61574, 271.24062, 300.58625, 
    389.47902, 323.26406, 303.8882, 287.85783, 320.78071, 260.5962, 
    329.16759, 322.44865, 288.50371, 230.97053, 341.00067, 317.60536, 
    334.04519, 242.21659, 273.88791, 319.75284, 303.14072, 369.25668, 
    315.38962, 238.82989, 389.86658, 291.40597, 256.2491, 328.59089, 
    270.08341, 346.88612, 351.05896, 313.98005, 276.49836, 341.01902, 
    304.44641, 279.94384, 297.38058, 260.15889, 301.88881, 385.34273, 
    281.3716, 305.96796, 235.56287, 313.06217, 242.71572, 354.28779, 
    305.7085, 256.87025, 288.9405, 291.11581, 307.62043, 321.73213, 
    283.82863, 248.89211, 291.42861, 273.85537, 307.50928, 316.5518, 
    321.39642, 289.61352, 319.72759, 339.1263, 364.61416, 277.72976, 
    295.74977, 274.09616, 272.9924, 272.49014, 251.05889, 251.01214, 
    386.34787, 245.74296, 303.75875, 284.2808, 350.74965, 354.9783, 
    229.63546, 282.53014, 233.23552, 252.86831, 264.47331, 320.17187, 
    357.86769, 281.28431, 291.52807, 309.28932, 335.37317, 250.08053, 
    279.77425, 370.20707, 313.44683, 293.07481, 250.40199, 270.51998, 
    391.40329, 234.55338, 376.94785, 332.07567, 246.3079, 299.29627, 
    313.21714, 285.05673, 285.967, 272.23878, 254.95618, 291.76139, 
    311.07348, 291.55214, 330.95787, 368.524, 230.85077, 259.26676, 
    269.73751, 284.4568, 331.74769, 267.65832, 297.71321, 327.10192, 
    281.02533, 317.82234, 277.43442, 347.61242, 242.73154, 273.46411, 
    326.03792, 228.83492, 292.92737, 304.29623, 275.46119, 298.80275, 
    343.8432, 343.49854, 280.61476, 290.29079, 251.7561, 249.89728, 
    297.3227, 298.18224, 355.51642, 310.46884, 337.82139, 307.61772, 
    313.36828, 334.1722, 305.46306, 278.88311, 278.72036, 267.1024, 
    320.97308, 343.18164, 263.62036, 256.22528, 309.85014, 288.59665, 
    235.3395, 314.77392, 321.25776, 300.35306, 371.13057, 259.11446, 
    258.48696, 306.43744, 323.78058, 280.04595, 297.34385, 263.67336, 
    329.24681, 233.97186, 346.51321, 286.97003, 306.86708, 297.15846, 
    337.82102, 262.12682, 291.70902, 281.91251, 297.9659, 217.23621, 
    359.04224, 265.45122, 324.9777, 334.42103, 237.77726, 228.74243, 
    252.22045, 290.07852, 283.7953, 270.72377, 295.45991, 302.80527, 
    304.19675, 268.4273, 244.94332, 263.11038, 207.48832, 326.08576, 
    312.77998, 318.79277, 244.6571, 332.0414, 259.87963, 296.28998, 
    239.8572, 248.63712, 312.60629, 247.72389, 242.67078, 271.98961, 
    322.73757, 197.99485, 342.45941, 246.40288, 246.54248, 270.31797, 
    279.19136, 283.27782, 256.21676, 298.22446, 245.34207, 363.90223, 
    206.35297, 297.69943, 250.76662, 299.09484, 296.26682, 217.5044, 
    323.62796, 290.34726, 246.24697, 290.60326, 313.243, 254.3545, 
    273.66298, 265.30058, 304.26679, 309.53028, 310.93268, 318.41836, 
    318.59416, 344.05085, 247.21871, 319.13724, 314.71633, 262.51803, 
    277.58658, 240.33522, 283.6671, 315.50305, 284.70172, 260.21957, 
    247.34008, 347.11825, 315.84204, 310.46298, 278.06065, 264.27623, 
    336.07573, 326.01364, 245.67, 149.19113, 298.48698, 222.68479, 
    303.39236, 305.14083, 303.49802, 261.84537, 341.96969, 334.29589, 
    221.43909, 307.37339, 258.84784, 319.13495, 241.58692, 239.09068, 
    242.53418, 330.78695, 280.48138, 310.41672, 263.1502, 267.58253, 
    187.53822, 262.62308, 295.44728, 266.01227, 313.69862, 253.52788, 
    256.41986, 323.6009, 337.53842, 333.99872, 303.51809, 312.28169, 
    294.92838, 300.70826, 300.24336, 187.73782, 276.88791, 286.49432, 
    292.1261, 254.85939, 277.5201, 243.95193, 251.41231, 300.05949, 
    307.55581, 308.63016, 292.26692, 322.59732, 314.09203, 279.01204, 
    104.22403, 282.82249, 310.19937, 265.4532, 298.59688, 327.82834, 
    216.9004, 304.42974, 308.75751, 353.56875, 323.77259, 301.02944, 
    243.21455, 299.93867, 239.32609, 288.85644, 321.70498, 300.7652, 
    214.00534, 330.58371, 218.42779, 226.38351, 269.54573, 281.0985, 
    313.38796, 315.12442, 338.55295, 287.76669, 276.50012, 283.05571, 
    293.54309, 313.50773, 251.84096, 306.30878, 298.6039, 282.81368, 
    280.57491, 246.21204, 228.88241, 278.85273, 250.53517, 308.06586, 
    337.51522, 322.46427, 249.82595, 326.33555, 223.46005, 292.20952, 
    326.24258, 284.81759, 361.99513, 225.74007, 265.54327, 301.95898, 
    289.31911, 306.88864, 312.2168, 227.28386, 288.40244, 274.2207, 
    281.3788, 295.98457, 291.69465, 233.11237, 327.41621, 238.52888, 
    246.48451, 272.98087, 300.54158, 265.74598, 205.12706, 296.53577, 
    350.87861, 247.59947, 315.72462, 285.2722, 269.48033, 243.84168, 
    283.6546, 275.47676, 290.5681, 252.84893, 341.91242, 268.79573, 
    304.94915, 251.56578, 263.95641, 243.55776, 338.59661, 303.00255, 
    212.9379, 292.68837, 294.13636, 388.07221, 303.7387, 313.72581, 
    355.13609, 317.09882, 331.7978, 218.43844, 262.96991, 306.87193, 
    268.31627, 265.33588, 320.67174, 247.42967, 276.86054, 273.34922, 
    348.14517, 267.12308, 306.68901, 177.57379, 242.70165, 216.52883, 
    255.14138, 224.94714, 252.34893, 235.99393, 311.64778, 336.18343, 
    287.39269, 336.26041, 289.42778, 192.66316, 276.65478, 306.98647, 
    198.9643, 302.39132, 182.62885, 346.2712, 309.66977, 264.90717, 
    302.69623, 264.56688, 277.51619, 339.16197, 280.54847, 277.54282, 
    283.37459, 292.15455, 292.34224, 252.94767, 301.60766, 301.46605, 
    289.27154, 286.94408, 288.05704, 233.64855, 304.36141, 278.99481, 
    260.61019, 257.88718, 279.99577, 269.7465, 293.24509, 323.32979, 
    315.02618, 246.47989, 327.3044, 274.86892)), row.names = c(29L, 
47L, 59L, 116L, 125L, 155L, 238L, 245L, 335L, 354L, 393L, 410L, 
420L, 443L, 478L, 514L, 584L, 665L, 676L, 720L, 737L, 766L, 782L, 
839L, 840L, 842L, 857L, 866L, 885L, 887L, 1017L, 1041L, 1083L, 
1086L, 1153L, 1207L, 1219L, 1231L, 1276L, 1283L, 1389L, 1405L, 
1423L, 1469L, 1517L, 1525L, 1544L, 1686L, 1766L, 1769L, 1773L, 
1841L, 1854L, 1885L, 1925L, 1932L, 1956L, 1992L, 2067L, 2094L, 
2105L, 2169L, 2262L, 2291L, 2293L, 2310L, 2349L, 2353L, 2358L, 
2385L, 2441L, 2456L, 2490L, 2516L, 2545L, 2552L, 2557L, 2676L, 
2683L, 2702L, 2733L, 2761L, 2801L, 2851L, 2876L, 2881L, 2882L, 
2913L, 2927L, 2928L, 2991L, 3001L, 3018L, 3042L, 3071L, 3209L, 
3239L, 3296L, 3298L, 3371L, 3502L, 3546L, 3559L, 3560L, 3561L, 
3566L, 3589L, 3659L, 3669L, 3714L, 3717L, 3738L, 3744L, 3765L, 
3768L, 3778L, 3782L, 3826L, 3840L, 3842L, 3848L, 3894L, 3968L, 
3972L, 3984L, 4007L, 4064L, 4103L, 4160L, 4209L, 4212L, 4337L, 
4377L, 4432L, 4671L, 4674L, 4675L, 4686L, 4714L, 4724L, 4761L, 
4773L, 4853L, 4871L, 4908L, 4931L, 4993L, 5000L, 5039L, 5055L, 
5081L, 5100L, 5173L, 5260L, 5265L, 5281L, 5331L, 5368L, 5412L, 
5419L, 5435L, 5476L, 5482L, 5485L, 5500L, 5561L, 5591L, 5618L, 
5629L, 5641L, 5745L, 5767L, 5783L, 5833L, 5876L, 5884L, 5933L, 
5938L, 5943L, 5960L, 5997L, 6000L, 6016L, 6021L, 6109L, 6116L, 
6124L, 6135L, 6157L, 6166L, 6172L, 6173L, 6176L, 6181L, 6214L, 
6216L, 6226L, 6229L, 6264L, 6280L, 6282L, 6315L, 6330L, 6358L, 
6366L, 6368L, 6375L, 6397L, 6463L, 6541L, 6543L, 6598L, 6604L, 
6644L, 6649L, 6669L, 6690L, 6692L, 6702L, 6711L, 6716L, 6718L, 
6725L, 6740L, 6769L, 6775L, 6781L, 6829L, 6841L, 6853L, 6860L, 
6872L, 6890L, 6891L, 6902L, 6905L, 6913L, 6914L, 6927L, 6934L, 
6937L, 6947L, 6965L, 6980L, 6981L, 7021L, 7072L, 7094L, 7104L, 
7121L, 7136L, 7138L, 7148L, 7149L, 7168L, 7169L, 7222L, 7258L, 
7263L, 7266L, 7292L, 7347L, 7350L, 7360L, 7382L, 7390L, 7419L, 
7423L, 7455L, 7463L, 7471L, 7482L, 7509L, 7528L, 7543L, 7577L, 
7583L, 7587L, 7593L, 7615L, 7616L, 7617L, 7633L, 7650L, 7654L, 
7674L, 7688L, 7706L, 7718L, 7723L, 7748L, 7766L, 7797L, 7811L, 
7813L, 7820L, 7839L, 7893L, 7899L, 7910L, 7926L, 7944L, 7945L, 
7947L, 7954L, 7955L, 7959L, 7982L, 7990L, 8025L, 8031L, 8041L, 
8044L, 8049L, 8062L, 8069L, 8072L, 8085L, 8090L, 8110L, 8122L, 
8134L, 8141L, 8193L, 8196L, 8201L, 8203L, 8208L, 8233L, 8234L, 
8236L, 8271L, 8273L, 8276L, 8284L, 8307L, 8328L, 8333L, 8354L, 
8367L, 8386L, 8412L, 8421L, 8441L, 8452L, 8478L, 8488L, 8504L, 
8509L, 8518L, 8534L, 8548L, 8558L, 8574L, 8578L, 8585L, 8620L, 
8654L, 8660L, 8662L, 8663L, 8704L, 8707L, 8733L, 8751L, 8757L, 
8817L, 8822L, 8824L, 8831L, 8840L, 8841L, 8851L, 8858L, 8877L, 
8904L, 8919L, 8944L, 8945L, 8951L, 8954L, 8959L, 8966L, 8986L, 
9049L, 9058L, 9075L, 9088L, 9111L, 9124L, 9132L, 9138L, 9148L, 
9171L, 9183L, 9188L, 9207L, 9257L, 9280L, 9284L, 9288L, 9292L, 
9316L, 9335L, 9341L, 9354L, 9392L, 9428L, 9439L, 9451L, 9483L, 
9484L, 9493L, 9498L, 9532L, 9542L, 9566L, 9569L, 9582L, 9592L, 
9613L, 9628L, 9634L, 9643L, 9647L, 9659L, 9665L, 9687L, 9697L, 
9708L, 9713L, 9762L, 9773L, 9815L, 9825L, 9829L, 9830L, 9839L, 
9842L, 9848L, 9854L, 9865L, 9868L, 9891L, 9896L, 9925L, 9945L, 
10012L, 10023L, 10035L, 10046L, 10059L, 10067L, 10096L, 10105L, 
10106L, 10137L, 10146L, 10154L, 10173L, 10178L, 10195L, 10201L, 
10202L, 10233L, 10243L, 10259L, 10273L, 10277L, 10287L, 10288L, 
10315L, 10316L, 10342L, 10345L, 10348L, 10354L, 10361L, 10372L, 
10417L, 10420L, 10430L, 10454L, 10476L, 10477L, 10490L, 10498L, 
10499L, 10532L, 10533L, 10550L, 10553L, 10557L, 10560L, 10572L, 
10616L, 10663L, 10667L, 10687L, 10712L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to add another column here with values taken from another data. The other data is this one:

```
> dput(new)
structure(list(CNTRYID = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Czech Republic", 
"Denmark", "France", "Greece", "Hungary", "Italy", "Lithuania", 
"Netherlands", "Poland", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Spain", 
"United Kingdom"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(184, 518), Mean = c(299.71, 
294.09), s.e. = c(4.39, 2.28), SD = c(36.73, 44.8), s.e = c(3.4, 
2.12)), row.names = 1:2, class = c("intsvy.mean", "data.frame"
))
```

What I want to do is to take the value under Mean from the second data.frame that is associated with, e.g. the Czech Republic, and put it in the first data.frame so that everywhere where CNTRYID is Czech Republic the value 299.71 to appear in a new column, say, test$MEAN. Then 294.09 to appear in every row where the CNTRYID is Denmark and so on. You might require package "intsvy" since one of the classes here is "intsvy.mean". I have extracted this from a large dataset I am working with, so there might be some additional labels etc. but, overall, you should be able to reproduce it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is an obvious case for a "merge" sometimes called "join". There are ahuge number of worked examples on SO. You should look at the documentation and educate yourself about the various types of such operations. You should not need an extra package, since the second object inherits from class "data.frame".

Comment: So simple, and I was banging my head for quite some time now... Thank you for the prompt response!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `merge`.

```
result <- merge(test,new,by="CNTRYID")
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I am always looking to find difficult solutions to my problems when in fact the answer is in simplicity!